# Containers doesn't start after doing docker-compose up -d

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, mariadb

i'm having some problems using dockers.

First of all, i did a docker-compose.yml:

```
version:  "3.9"

services:
   web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - 8000:80
    volumes:
     - $HOME/sitios:/var/www/html
   db:
    build: .
    ports:
     - 3000:3306
    volumes:
     - $HOME/"mariadb copia":/var/lib
```

As you can see here, i want to make a docker with two volumes, one with HTTP and other with mariadb server.
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install nano mariadb-server apache2 -y
```

Then, i use the command `sudo docker-compose up -d`, however, the docker doesn't start at all, i try `sudo docker start <name>` but it doesn't work.

I already googled and i already looked into the official docker documentation but i can't find anything.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: do you have a specific use case for installing both applications in the same container? its kind of against containers purpose in general. if you're going to split it I'd use the official images for each [1](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb) [2](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd), and if not, advice their official images docker files to take reference in the official way to do so by the publisher

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using `ubuntu:latest` you're missing an entrypoint.

So it starts but immediately exits with exit 0.

Another thing: do not do `apt upgrade` inside the `dockerfile`, just take another Image (with a higher version or whatever you looking for).

One more thing: you use two different services, in the same image, it's pretty weird.

And one last thing: use the official Images, so you do not have to build them yourself.

Comment: Hi, I did the entrypoint and it doesn't start. I want to make a ubuntu:latest image with mariadb and apache2 installed, however it seems that it doesn't work.

Comment: Typically you'd create two separate images, one with MariaDB and one with Apache (or as suggested here use the prebuilt [`mariadb`](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb) and [`httpd`](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd) images).